# Проблема с редактированием xml файла

Tags: c#, xml

Имеется проблема при работе с XML файлом. В нём присутствует вёрстка. В коде не хочет входить в цикл для редактирования значения элементов.
Вот пример.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("arrived.xml");

foreach (XElement xe in xdoc.Root.Elements("body2").ToList())
{

}
```

А вот XML

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->
<htmlx xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<body2> </body2>
</htmlx>
```

Причём, если вместо xmlns в Root указать, допустим, xmlns1, то в цикл входит и работает без проблем, но тогда слетает вёрстка.
Как вариант в шаблоне XML изначально указывать xmlns1,а при сохранении переименовывать параметр, но это костыли.

Comment: Пожалуйста, отредактируйте свой пост и добавьте текстовый XML и код c#. Картинки бесполезны.

Answer (score 1):

Причина тривиальна: в стандарте нет body2 поэтому когда вы указываете стандарт w3c через xmlns - то элемента нет. Когда убираете использовать стандарт убирая xmlns (а переименовывая вы его убираете из документа) вы получаете нестандартный элемент.

А чего вы хотели? Вы работаете якобы по стандарту, но у вас body2 -- и поэтому о каких костылях может идти речь? Хотите стандарт - соблюдайте стандарт, не будет костылей. Если "xml не мой", обратитесь к автору и бейте по рукам, но уговаривайте использовать стандартную схему (и тогда вы сможете использовать валидацию по xsd и обосновывать отказ в обработке файла), либо ставьте костыли разного рода.

Comment: Да, xml не мой, взял для шаблона своей задачи,ибо все элементы и атрибуты подходят. Но при редактировании через Linq вот такие проблемы. Походу остаётся костыли делать

Answer (score 1):

Вы не можете использовать `xmlns1`. Это атрибут. Пространство имен по умолчанию всегда `xmlns`.

Ваш XML имеет пространство имен по умолчанию (default namespace). Ниже вы узнаете, как правильно с ним работать.

Все элементы XML ниже корневого узла принадлежат пространству имен по умолчанию. Даже если вы не видите его в XML.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    const string fileName = @"e:\Temp\Anton.xml";
    
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

    // получить пространство имен по умолчанию
    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    foreach (XElement xe in xdoc.Root.Elements(ns + "body2"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xe.Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, попробую завтра

Comment: этот способ сработает.